# Diretório dos scripts não são reconhecidos

Tags: wordpress, diretório

Estou montando um site wordpress no MAMP instalado no windows e os scripts .JS coloco assim no footer:

```
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" 
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
           integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" 
           crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/efeitos.js">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Daí que não funciona e no console reconhece como "GET http://localhost:8888/protodesign/assets/js/efeitos.js net::ERR_ABORTED"

Nos outros sites q eu fiz sempre deu certo colocando o diretório somente a partir da pasta assets, mas agora não deu certo.

o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que a pasta `assets` exista dentro do seu tema, o caminho dela provavelmente é `wp-content/themes/nomedotema/assets/`. Como está, o PHP busca em `/assets` e não encontra nada.

Isso posto, você não está usando os métodos corretos para inserir scripts em um tema WordPress. Ao invés de colocar as tags no arquivo do template, use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), assim:

No arquivo `functions.php`:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adiciona_scripts' );
function adiciona_scripts() {

    // jQuery já vem por padrão com o WP, então a chamada simples resolve,
    // você pode usar uma igual às outras abaixo se quiser mesmo buscar da CDN
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); 

    // Scripts externos são chamados assim, veja o significado de cada atributo no link acima.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'efeitos', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/efeitos.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
}
```

No arquivo `footer.php`:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```